# How can I Access to all rows in DevExpress GridControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, devexpress, rows

I'm using `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView` in my WinForm application via c#, i want to access to Rows of this grid and use Tag property of each row for save some data, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experiment shows that DevExpress's `GridView` does not hold special row objects for each row, like .NET's `DataGridView` does. To be fast and efficient on large data, it operates in *virtual* mode and renders each row on the fly, anytime needed. When accessing rows in the grid (using [`GetRow`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic) method for example), you actually get the object you originally passed to the grid's data source.

To store additional information about your data, the best option is to use a separate dictionary, keyed on row handle (index) or your own data object. You can also add an additional field in your original data object to hold the data.